# Unable to start Karate debug server in Visual Studio Code, Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-code, karate

I am trying to use Karate with Visual Studio Code. I have followed the instructions to set up Karate on VSC for Windows, with the robot and Karate Zip. I am able to run the examples in the zip when I run Karate directly. But when I try to debug using VS Code and the standalone jar I keep getting the error that the server cannot start because it times out. I have tried cleaning up VS Code and installing Karate plug in only, Java JRE 1.8 version, disabled the windows 10 firewall. I attach the error screenshots showing debug server timeout. I have tried Karate versions 0.9.6 and 0.9.9RC3 both with the same problem.

```
[enter image description here][1]
[enter image description here][2]
[enter image description here][3]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTEEM.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bULiN.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/69T9T.png
```

Answer (score 1):

either karate.jar is failing to create `target\karate-debug-port.txt` file or vscode extension is failing to detect it

check if file was created and/or what may be preventing this file to be created